# display a panel at bottom of display screen actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, fullscreen

I have a problem to maintain full screen of my flash player built in flex and as3 using osmf
I want to display panel bar right at the bottom of user's screen. This should work on all screen resolution. What I am doing currently is working fine to display video on full screen but issue is that its not aligning control panel of video accordingly.
What I have currently is this

`stage.fullScreenSourceRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, fsvideoContainerW , fsvideoContainerH);
                            videoContainer.width = fsvideoContainerW;
                            videoContainer.height = fsvideoContainerH;
                            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;
                            stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;`

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see code dedicated to the positioning controls in your code. Main idea when you create resizable components is to listen to the Event.RESIZE. Here is an small snippet how it works:

```
package {

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class StackOverflow extends Sprite {
        private var _playerControls:VideoPlayerControls;

        public function StackOverflow() {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);
        }

        private function onAdded(e:Event):void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);


            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

            setup();
        }

        private function setup():void {
            //Main event that will help you reposition and resize your UI components
            stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onResize);

            _playerControls = new VideoPlayerControls();

            addChild(_playerControls)
        }

        private function onResize(e:Event):void {
            _playerControls.updateWidth(stage.stageWidth);
            _playerControls.y = stage.stageHeight - _playerControls.height;
        }

    }
}

import flash.display.Sprite;

internal class VideoPlayerControls extends Sprite {

    public function VideoPlayerControls() {
        this.graphics.beginFill(0x333333);
        this.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 40);
    }

    internal function updateWidth(width:int):void {
        //Do logic with reposition and resizing components
        this.width = width;
    }
}
```

Stage properties `align` and `scaleMode` should be set only once at startup of you video player.

Comment: thank you for your urgent reply.
Well I have another issue too if you can help. My broadcaster is not working in chrome but working perfect in firefox and any other browsers. I have tried everything and found that its due to pepper flash plugin already built-in chrome. So how may i handle this issue. The issue that I am having is that it is not allowing to click on flash security setting options. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Security window has very limited interface. There are several bugs with it in various browsers (not clickable one of them...), especially under Mac. I can recommend add this as bug in Adobe Bug Tracker.